# ListSelectionModel and listener

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I've a JTable with a ListSelectionModel and ListSelectionListener.

The selection model is set in the JTables constructor: `lsm.getSelectionModel()`

and the ListSelectionListener is set via a public method:

```
    public void setListSelectionListener(ListSelectionListener l){
        lsm.addListSelectionListener(l);
    }
```

called from the Controller class:

```
    view.setTableSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                int viewRow = e.getFirstIndex();
                System.out.println(viewRow + " is selected");                  
            }
        }
    });
```

because the listener is created in another class I can't use the JTable's `getSelectedRow();` method, but using the ListSelectionEvent object's `getFirstIndex();` obviously doesn't get the current selection.

So I'm now using `int viewRow = ((ListSelectionModel)e.getSource()).getLeadSelectionIndex());`

Does that seem like the correct way to get the current selection? It seems to be working, but I'm not sure if this is a bad way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only getMinSelectionIndex() and getMaxSelectionIndex() works, which returns the min and max of selected indices respectively. Lead/anchor selected index may >= 0 even when there is no selected row.